# Windows start menu system color background for icons

Tags: windows-10, colors, icons, start-menu

For a while now Windows has been updating its icons for system apps. While they look nice, they also now have a fixed blue background colour in the start menu (image below). How can I set these to also use the red background colour applied to all the other icons, if that's even possible at all?

If it's of any significance, the system colour (red here) is chosen automatically based on the desktop background.

[image]

Comment: Maybe try setting the color to something else and then setting it back to desktop-complimentary-chosen. Kind of like refreshing it.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work with a static colour either, or even with a reboot in between.

Comment: Oh, yeah, just noticed it does the same thing on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to customize the colors of start menu icons with a utility called [Tileconfier](https://github.com/Jonno12345/TileIconifier/releases) (created by Stack Exchange user [jonno](https://superuser.com/users/536125/jonno)) which is a small open source utility to create full tile icons in Windows 8.1 and 10. Users have the option of using a HEX code to match colors exactly, or use the eyedropper tool.

For more detailed instructions please view [this Stack Exchange post](https://superuser.com/a/1033361/598567)

[image]